# $(A[1])^{\otimes n}\backsimeq (A^{\otimes n})[n]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

When $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded module, $A[1]$ is the *shift or suspension* of $A$ (i.e $(A[1])^{i}=A^{i+1}$). May the $n$th power tensor of the shift be identified in this way?. Am I missing anything?. What if $A$ is a differential graded algebra?.

Comment: Yes (not quite a research level question though).

Comment: Victor, you can definitely ask this question in MSE! You can see this by replacing a string $sa_1sa_2\cdots sa_n$ by $s^n a_1\cdots a_n$, introducing the appropriate Koszul sign.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation. Indeed, this was not a research level question, I just wanted make sure I did not omit anything.